# How to get value in QAbstractProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)?

Tags: c++, qt

One of the columns of my QTableView contains time in seconds. I want it to be in munites, so I need to divide it by 60 and append what's left as seconds.

I created a proxy table for this purpose and redefined the `data` method. But how can I get the actual data that is contained in the corresponding cell?

I googled, but no result. I'm an absolute newbie to QT and to C++ in general and I'm a little confused about not being able to see code behind every method in the documentation.

For example, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data contains just a description. If I saw the implementation of this method I would understand immediately hot to get the data.

Obviously I don't understand something important here in QT-programming...

This is my last attempt (not working)

```
QVariant ProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return this->itemData(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the default querymodel example in Qt creator I figure it out, it is very simple:

```
QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
```

You just need to call the parent method.
It's so obvious, don't know why I didn't realize it before.